# CodeIgniter send multiple responses to client

Tags: codeigniter

Is there any way when the client sends a request to the CodeIgniter server that it can respond with multiple responses?

For example, this can be a file upload to show how the file is processed in the backend.

Can this be done with an ajax request or do I need sockets for this?

EDIT:

Example situation here

> I send a data object to the CI backend to be saved. Let's say on the
>   backend the following functions has to run on this received data
>
> 1. Inspect data to be secure
> 2. search for any similar data
> 3. Save data
> 4. Create a page based on the data
> 5. add some default images to this new page

As you see, these functions may take more then 5 seconds to execute.

Do I need a response from the server every time a task from the list above is completed? Does that make sense?

Another example would be when task 1 is complete the server will send a response saying that task 1 has completed. So the user knows that something is going on.

Comment: your question is not clear. tell us more or show what you've tried and what actually you want?

Comment: @Md.KhairulIslam I added an example situation, hope it helps

Comment: you probably misunderstood about server side and client side communication, if once server return to the client side then it wouldn't go back by itself until client makes a new request. but if i understand your problem then you can do one thing- when server process client's request you can show a progress bar to make sure the client that request is under processing.

Comment: just create nested ajax requests. Meaning if first ajax is success then proceed with the next request. and so on. As long as you place each ajax request (which represents each task) inside the `success` method of the previous ajax request.

Comment: @CodeGodie I dont know about that messy nesting... There has to be a better way

Comment: Any answer with Socket io